# Fourier Transform inconsistency in time domain and frequency domain

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing, sampling

We know that sampling a continuous signal and converting it into discrete signal can be represented by timing an impulse train on the original signal and then scaling at time axis.
The procedure described above in frequency domain is like the figure below, where the $T$ is the sampling period, $\omega_{M}$ is the maximum frequency component in original signal.

[sampling procedure in frequency domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUnZr.jpg)

We can see that the spectrum has a scaling factor $\frac{1}{T}$ here.
Now if the continuous signal is $cos(20t)$ and the sampling period $T$ is $\frac{\pi}{50}$, the sampled discrete signal $x_s[n]$ can be expressed as
$$ x(t) = cos(20t) $$
$$ x_s[n] = x(nT) = cos(20 \cdot n\frac{\pi}{50}) = cos(\frac{2\pi}{5}n) $$

Let the Fourier Transform of original signal is denoted by $X(j\omega)$ and the Fourier Transform of sampled discrete signal is denoted
by $X_s(e^{j\omega})$. By looking at the FT table, their expression are
$$ X(j\omega) = \pi\{\delta(\omega - 20) + \delta(\omega + 20)\}$$
and $$ X_{s}(e^{j\omega}) = \pi\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}\{\delta(\omega-\frac{2\pi}{5} - 2\pi l) + \delta(\omega+\frac{2\pi}{5} - 2\pi l)\}$$

My problem is where does the scaling factor $\frac{1}{T}$ in $X_{s}(e^{j\omega})$ go?

Comment: The derivation of the final expression involves the Fourier transform of the impulse train, and it is there where the $1/T$ factor first appears. Your should be able to find the details in any signals and systems textbook.

Comment: The last expression doesn't have $\frac{1}{T}$ factor. That's where I don't understand.